# Connecting from local computer to server - ssh

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, ssh-keygen

This is procedure that I use:

```
$ cd .ssh
bash: cd: .ssh: No such file or directory

$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa):
- ENTER -
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
- ENTER -
Enter same passphrase again:
- ENTER -
Your identification has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256: "hugecode" user@user
The key's randomart image is:
"lots of characters"

$ cd .ssh
$ sudo nano config

Host user IP addr
  HostName IP addr
  User user
  PreferredAuthentications publickey
  IdentfyFile /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa

Host server IP
  HostName IP
  User server
  Port no.of port

- Close config -

$ ssh server
/home/user/.ssh/config: line 5: Bad configuration option: identfyfile
/home/user/.ssh/config: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
```

I need a solution for this.

Comment: replace **IdentfyFile** by **IdentityFile**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misspelled Ident**i**tyFile :

> /home/user/.ssh/config: line 5: Bad configuration option: identfyfile

Comment: Thank you very much, I havent noticed that at all, thought that problem is something with keys.